# has anyone tried to use an intersect table instead of oracle-apex list of values' storing method

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

ApEx as you know stores the multiple choices list of values in a single column by separating the values with ':' like this

```
qwe:rty:yui:opa:sdf:ghj
```

but this is not how a database should function, there should should be a middle table with foreign keys.
so my question is has anyone tried to do it the right way or do i just stick with ApEx's method? and is there no risk of errors if so?
i am not very experienced with apex so i still don't know how to insert into 2 tables at the same time, if anyone can tell me how maybe i can find a solution on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in a multi-select are treated as colon separated lists in APEX, but you have all the freedom you want in storing your data. There is no built-in support for multi selects (probably because there are many ways to implement this on the backend) but it's not too hard to implement the logic yourself.

Allow me to illustratie with an example. There is a  table `TEAMS` (primary key `TEAM_ID`) with a child table `MEMBERS` (primary key `MEMBER_ID`) and an intersect table `TEAM_MEMBERS` (primary key `TEAM_MEMBER_ID` - auto generated).
In the teams form there is a page item `P1_TEAM_MEMBERS` of type select list with "Allow Multi Selection" set to "on".
There are 2 parts to this:

1. getting the data from the intersect table into page item on page load
2. processing the data on submit.

(1) The first part is pretty simple. You create a computation (to run AFTER the Form Initialization Process) on `P1_TEAM_MEMBERS` of type "SQL Query (return colon separated values)". This type of computation is created specifically for handling multi selects. The source would be

```
SELECT member_id FROM team_members WHERE team_id = :P1_TEAM_ID
```

If you want to have more control, you can also take type "SQL Query (return single value)" and us `LISTAGG` to convert the columns to a colon separated string.

(2) For processing the data you can use an application process to be executed AFTER the Automatic Row Processing process. This is because you need primary key value (`P1_TEAM` in our case) of the master table if you want to create a new team with members. In my code I use another page item `P1_TEAM_MEMBERS_OLD` thas has original values of team members. It also has a colon delimited string and it is computed just before this page process.
The plsql API `apex_string` offers a could of very useful functions. `apex_string.split` takes a string with separators and converts that to a pl/sql collection.
Use `MULTISET` to identify the differences in the old and new value.

```
DECLARE
  l_old_team_members apex_t_varchar2;
  l_new_team_members apex_t_varchar2;
  l_members_added apex_t_varchar2;
  l_members_removed apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN
  l_old_team_members := apex_string.split(:P1_MEMBERS_OLD,':');
  l_new_team_members := apex_string.split(:P1_MEMBERS,':');
  l_members_added := l_new_team MULTISET EXCEPT l_old_team;
  l_members_removed := l_old_team MULTISET EXCEPT l_new_team;
  -- add new team members
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_members_added.COUNT LOOP
    INSERT INTO team_members(team_id, member_id)
      VALUES (:P1_TEAM_ID,l_members_added(i));
  END LOOP;
  -- delete removed team members
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_members_removed.COUNT LOOP
    DELETE FROM team_members WHERE team_id = :P1_TEAM_ID AND member_id = l_members_removed(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The downside to this code is that there is no lost update detection out of the box, but you can implement that manually if it is a requirement.

Comment: thanks for the answer it was helpful but what do you mean by "there is no lost update detection" if i may ask

Comment: If you use the out of the box form region, then you have "lost update detection". User A opens the form for row 1 and goes for coffee. User B opens the form for row 1 and changes data. He saves. When user A now would save his data the changes of user B will be overwritten. That is a lost update. If there is lost update detection then user A will get an error message indicating the data changed while he was making the change.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, either you use what Apex provides (which is a colon-separated list of values), or you "invent" your own solution.

I don't know why they (Oracle) chose to do it that way, but yes - it is annoying. You can't store those values properly into a table, can't enforce referential integrity constraint, have "problems" when writing reports (as we usually store `ID`s and display `names` so we have to convert column into rows; not that you can't do it, just saying), ...

As I don't have (too) many multi-select items, I kind of live with what I have, but I don't like it.

Comment: same here, i tried on some occasions to add a dynamic action that takes the values and insert them in a table but it had to be be done in another modal dialog page, it is not a very elegant solution so i don't use it much.
let's hope oracle include a better solution in the future :-)