# Dynamically generate a checkbox group, loop through checked/unchecked values in pl/sql

Tags: checkbox, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex version 22.2 and this is my first time working with a dynamic checkbox group. Each company has a list of "ParentID's" that they can do business under. The number of PIDs a company can have is from 1-20. I'm using a sql query LOV to display all of the PIDs via checkbox group

```
select 
    ms.subid as ParentID,
    ms.keyid as KeyID 
from 
    memmgr.merchant_subid ms 
join
    sandro.account_lookup al on
        ms.keyid = al.merchantkeyid
where
    orgkeyid = :P1_ORGKEYID
order by 
    ms.subid;
```

My next objective is to create a process in which I loop through the selected checkboxes and insert the keyids into my other table named `Portal_Parents` . I'm fairly certain I can obtain this by using `apex_string.split_numbers(:P10_CHECKBOX,':')`.

The part I'm not sure about is how to initialize these checkboxes after the initial insert, and what the best way to manage these updates would be. I still need for all of the checkboxes to appear as they would in the code above. But I need the ones that exist in my `Portal_Parents` table to be checked. If I can figure out how to initialize each checkbox as either checked or unchecked by using a query such as:

```
select 1 
from portal_parents 
where portalloginkeyid = :P10_PORTALLOGINKEYID 
and merchantkeyid = {This checkboxes' keyid}`
```

For my update statement, I would basically have to loop through all of the checked values, use a query to see if they already exist in the portal_parents table, then either insert or do nothing depending on if they exist. I would also then have to loop through all of the unchecked boxes, use the same query to see whether they exist in portal_parents, then either delete or do nothing depending on whether they exist.

This seems like a plausible solution to me, but please let me know if I should change directions. If not my only real unknown is to figure out how to use the checkboxes keyid to determine whether it should be checked or not, and how to select for the checked and unchecked boxes into pl/sql variables to be used for processing. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150266/has-anyone-tried-to-use-an-intersect-table-instead-of-oracle-apex-list-of-values). It has an example on how to initialize a multi value component (shuttle / checbox) and an example of an update (delete unchecked and insert new)

Comment: @KoenLostire With just a little bit of fiddling I was able to apply your solution to my checkbox. This works exactly as expected. Can you tell me how to mark my question as answered by the link you gave me? Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on how to answer your own question - probably best to answer it yourself, feel free to mention the link to the other. Or - maybe even better - close it as duplicate of that other one. I haven't done it myself yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to obtain this answer through @KoenLostrie link here: [has anyone tried to use an intersect table instead of oracle-apex list of values' storing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150266/has-anyone-tried-to-use-an-intersect-table-instead-of-oracle-apex-list-of-values).

Everything works relatively the same for a checkbox group. One of the important things I changed was moving the computation that initializes the checkboxes into the source of my checkbox item. So my query that displays all the parentid's is in the LOV, and the query that selects which boxes should be checked is in the source. It's also important to note that this item's session state must be set to per request to work correctly.